# What does it mean by "if the value can be represented by the new type"?

Tags: c, type-conversion, integer

In C11 standard

> **6.3.1.3  Signed and unsigned integers**
>
> 1 When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type
> other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it
> is unchanged.
>
> 2 Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
> repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
> can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
> the new type. 60)
>
> 3 Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be
> represented in it; either the result is implementation-deﬁned or an
> implementation-deﬁned signal is raised.

In the first point,

- I was wondering what it means by "if the value can be represented by the new type" in the first point? Two integer types might have different ranges of integers, but can have the same range of bit representations. (For example, unsigned int and int.)
- Are both the bit representation and the integer value not changed before and after the conversion?

Comment: If the value is 30000, and you cast it to an 8-bit signed char, that new type isn't large enough to hold the value of 30000, therefore the value cannot be represented by the new type.

Comment: Each integer type has an associated range of representable values. Mathematical integers outside that range are not representable by the type. For example, `int8_t` (if supported by the implementation) has a range of -128 to 127.

Comment: If you store `UINT_MAX` in an `int` object, the result will be implementation-defined, or an implementation-defined signal may be raised. "implementation-defined" means that the implementation has to document what it actually does, for example: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integers-implementation.html#Integers-implementation

Comment: Assuming [`CHAR_BIT == 8`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) (8 bits per byte), then an `unsigned char` can represent a value between 0 and 255, and a `signed char` can represent a value between `-128` and `127`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel `signed char` is not guaranteed to be able to represent `-128`.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Ah, yes, you are right. This is because [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) respresentation is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C standard does not dictate one specific representation for integers.  While most implementations you are likely to come across use two's complement for signed integers, that is not guaranteed.  It also allows for one's complement where negating a number means inverting all bits (and *not* adding 1 as two's complement does), or sign-and-magnitude where negating a number means inverting only the high order bit.

As such, the language of the standard talks about what happens to the *value* of an integer when it is converted, not the *representation*.

As an example, suppose an `int` has range -2<sup>31</sup> to 2<sup>31</sup>-1 and `unsigned int` has range 0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1.  If you have an `int` with the value 45 that is converted to `unsigned int`, that value can be represented in both types so now you have an `unsigned int` with value 45.

Now suppose your `int` has value -1000.  That value can not be represented in an `unsigned int` so it has to be converted as per the rule in clause 2, i.e. 2<sup>32</sup> is added to -1000 to result in 2<sup>32</sup> - 1000 == 4294966296.  Now in two's complement representation, an `unsigned int` with value 4294966296 and an `int` with value -1000 happen to have the same representation which is FFFFFC18 in hex.  This equivalence does **not** hold true for one's complement or sign-and-magnitude.

So converting a number to a different type may or may not change the representation, depending on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What I do not understand is why this standard definition is desired also it leads to wrong result when casting negative integer numbers to a bigger unsigned data type!

So if I e.g. have -1000 (0xFC18) as I16 (int) and cast it to U32 (unsigned long) according to the standard I will get -1000+2^32=4294966296 (0xFFFFFC18) what is a much different value than what expected (0x0000FC18) and the same as if I would have done a cast to I32.

So to cast correcly an I16 to U32 and to have the expected result I would need to do an explicit "old size unsigned cast" before going to the wider format u32_var=(U32)((U16)u16_var)? Why!?

So theoretically the standard should write somethng like
"
Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that could be represented in the **old type size as unsigned** until the value is in the range of the new type.
"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34991841)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).